# Define variable name with variable in LESS operation

Tags: less

Can someone please explain why this code doesn't work:

```
@red-1:#ff0000;
@red-2:#990000;
@blue-1:#000ff;
@blue-2:#00099;

.setTheme(@theme){
  @color-1:~"@{@{theme}-1}";
  @color-2:fade(~"@{@{theme}-2}", 10%); //doesn't work
  body.@{theme} .button{
    background:@color-1;
    color:@color-2;
  }
}

.setTheme(~"red");
```

Thanks;

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: The compiler shows the following error:
`Syntax error: error evaluating function `fade`: Object #<Object> has no method 'toHSL'.setTheme(~"red");`
I expect that the CSS output is following:`color: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is a Bug

Color functions have an issue with respect to this [that has been submitted](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1458).

### Workaround

Don't try to do both calls in one string. Set the variable value to your inner variables. Then when you use them, use the `@@` syntax directly. Like this:

```
@red-1:#ff0000;
@red-2:#990000;
@blue-1:#000ff;
@blue-2:#00099;

.setTheme(@theme){
  @color-1:~"@{theme}-1";
  @color-2:~"@{theme}-2"; 
  @color-2faded: fade(@@color-2, 10%);
  body.@{theme} .button{
    background:@@color-1;
    color:@color-2faded;
  }
}

.setTheme(~"red");
```

Or without the extra variable:

```
.setTheme(@theme){
  @color-1:~"@{theme}-1";
  @color-2:~"@{theme}-2"; 
  body.@{theme} .button{
    background:@@color-1;
    color: fade(@@color-2, 10%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the "color" function to convert a string to color

```
@color: '#ccc';
background: color(@color);
```

But yes, it didn't work on multi variables like your case. 
Resulted in **#NaNNaNNaN**