# Passing a variable name as a variable into the lighten function doesn't work

Tags: css, less

This works:

```
background-color: ~"@{@{space-name}-color-4}";
```

This does not:

```
background-color:lighten(~"@{@{space-name}-color-4}",5%);
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: error evaluating function `lighten`: Object # has no method 'toHSL' in ...

Checked questions on SO already and this one seems to be similar:

[Define variable name with variable in LESS operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098037/define-variable-name-with-variable-in-less-operation)

Unfortunately this did not work for me, when I used:

```
@color4:~"@{@{space-name}-color-4}";
border: 1px solid @color4; // this works
background-color:lighten(#ffffff,5%); // this works
background-color:lighten(@color4,5%); // this doesn't
background-color:lighten(@@color4,5%); // this doesn't - throws 'SyntaxError: variable @@{my-color-4} is undefined in..' although it is defined as @my-color-4 previously. Somehow double @ seems to fail
background-color:lighten(color(@color4),5%); // this doesn't
```

Seems to be something with https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1458 but I am not able to make a workaround as mentioned.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @@color4 method actually throws '...variable @@{my-color-4} is undefined...'. Variable is defined as: @my-color-4: darken(@my-color-1, 10%);

Comment: Ok, what is the version of Less that you are using and what value does `@my-color-1` have? The reason I am asking these questions because I am using 1.7.5 and with whatever values I use even `border: 1px solid @color4` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up mixins something like this:

```
@space-name: space;
@space-color-4: #123456;
@color4:~'@{space-name}-color-4';
```

Then in your class they can be used as follows:

```
.class {
  border: 5px solid @@color4; // this works
  background:lighten(@@color4,25%); // this also works
}
```

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/Eaoobr)

Comment: Hah, I nested @{space-name} and then the whole thing again, should have left it as a string. Thank you very much.