# LESS darken() doesn't seem to work with variable resolved from interpolation

Tags: less

The following LESS code fails to compile, despite the fact that `@color` is correctly resolved to `#3AD49E`. (Thanks to [Defining Variable Variables using LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198221/defining-variable-variables-using-less-css) .)

```
@success-color: #3AD49E;
@darken-percent: 5%;

.make-colored-div(@name) {
  @color: ~'@{@{name}-color}';
  &.@{name} {
    background: @color;
    border-color: darken(@color, @darken-percent);
  }
}

button {
    .make-colored-div(success);
}
```

Any ideas how to get darken to work?

Comment: This happens because you must convert `@color` in HSL space, before applying it `darken` function.

You should write this: `@color1: hsl(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color));` but strangley it does not run for generated  `@color` variable. If you replace it with original  `@succes-color` one, it runs correctly. I don't know if its a bug or a limitation

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451425/less-passing-variable-variable-into-lighten-function.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: dude, you are on this! Well spotted!

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you must convert `@color` in HSL space, before applying it `darken` function.

Key code should be:

```
@color1: hsl(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color));
```

But it does not run as is. You need to pass through a `@temp` variable, in order to do a double (and intermediate) passage to obtain HSL conversion. Complete code follows:

```
@success-color: #3AD49E;
@darken-percent: 5%;

.make-colored-div(@name) {
  @color: ~'@{@{name}-color}';
  &.@{name} {
    @temp:~'@{name}-color';
    @final-color: hsl(hue(@@temp), saturation(@@temp), lightness(@@temp));
    background: @final-color;
    border-color: darken(@final-color, @darken-percent);
  }
}

button {
    .make-colored-div(success);
}
```